# UFW 0.35 - Redirect incoming port 2121 to port 21 on VM (other interface)

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, port-forwarding, ufw, ip-forwarding

I'm posting here because I've got a server, and I want to redirect the port 2121 of my main interface (eth0) to the port 21 of my secondary interface (virbr0).

This is my configuration :

```
Physical server OS : Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS, 
Firewall software : UFW v.0.35 
Virtual Machine OS : Windows 7 Professional
Hypervisor : OpenStack KVM (QEMU).
```

Server IP configuration :

```
 eth0
        address 91.121.XXX.XXX
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 91.121.XXX.0
        broadcast 91.121.XXX.255
        gateway 91.121.XXX.254

 virbr0
        address 192.168.122.1
        gateway 192.168.122.1
```

Server Routes configuration :

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         91.121.XXX.254  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
91.121.XXX.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

UFW configuration :

```
I have followed these instructions : 
NAT and FORWARD with Ubuntu’s ufw firewall - https://gist.github.com/kimus/9315140
```

VM IP Configuration :

```
IP address : 192.168.122.59
GATEWAY : 192.168.122.1
```

---

This is that I want to do :

```
redirect 91.121.XXX.XXX:2121 to 192.168.122.59:21 (VM).
eth0:2121 -> virbr0:21
```

Note :
The VM is connected to the Internet, for some reasons, I want to access at the FTP (Typsoft) Server installed on it on port 21 .

The port 21 of my server is already on use by an other thing. And I want use the port 2121 to access the ftp server present on the VM.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used UFW for my iptables configuration. I've always used cmd-line iptables/bash scripts to accomplish my firewalling. So my answer here is going to be in that format.

This rule is to accomplish the NAT you want:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 91.121.XXX.XXX -p tcp --dport 2121 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.59:21
```

What it does is accept TCP connections on IP 91.121.XXX.XXX:2121 and NAT them to your VM on port 21.

Assuming your `FORWARD` policy is set to `DROP`, you'll also have to make sure you're allowing connections to your VM from the outside via:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.59 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

Both of these rules are REQUIRED in order for NAT/forwarding to work properly in your scenario (although, if your `FORWARD` policy is `ACCEPT` then the second rule in the `FORWARD` chain is unneeded).

If these don't work, then please post the output of `iptables -vnL` as well as `iptables -t nat -vnL` and I can assist further.

Hope this helps.